# Go Back with More Detail

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Back function, and it is growing.  I also think this is terrible, but I don't seem to get how it can be improved:

```cs
public void GoBack()
{
    NavButtonUsed = true;

    Forward.Insert(0, Back[0]);
    Back.RemoveAt(0);

    if (Back[0].Title.StartsWith(" ") && CurrentItem.Menu != Back[0].Menu)
    {
        switch (Back[0].Menu)
        {
            case Menus.WSOneNote:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[0];
                break;

            case Menus.WSMainMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("MainMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.MainMenu), Menus.WSMainMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSTextMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("TextMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.TextMenu), Menus.WSTextMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSTextBlockMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("TextBlockMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.TextBlockMenu), Menus.WSTextBlockMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSTableMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("TableMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.TableMenu), Menus.WSTableMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSTableCellsMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("TableCellsMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.TableCellsMenu), Menus.WSTableCellsMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSDrawMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("DrawMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.DrawMenu), Menus.WSDrawMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSDrawnItemsMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("DrawnItemsMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.DrawnItemsMenu), Menus.WSDrawnItemsMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSPictureMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("PictureMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.PictureMenu), Menus.WSPictureMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSFileMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("FileMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.File), Menus.WSFileMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSAppBarsMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("AppBarsMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.AppBar), Menus.WSAppBarsMenu))];
                break;

            case Menus.WSCharmsMenu:
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("CharmsMenu"), typeof(WindowsData.Charms), Menus.WSCharmsMenu))];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])];
    NavButtonUsed = false;
}
```

I have more menus to account for, but I haven't implemented going back to them yet as I do not have them fully implemented.  What is really going on here is I need to programmatically select a menu to open it so I can select a menu item within it.  If I do not open the menu, `ItemList` will not have `CurrentItem`, so the app will crash.

This is `CurrentItem`:

```cs
private MenuItem _currentItem = new MenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("OneNote"), typeof(WindowsData.OneNote), Menus.WSOneNote);
public MenuItem CurrentItem
{
    get
    { 
        return _currentItem;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _currentItem)
        {
            _currentItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

`ItemList`, `Back`, and `Forward` are just `ObservableCollection`s of `MenuItem`s (they can't be `List`s because they are bound to XAML objects that need to know when they are updated):

```cs
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Back { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Forward { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ItemList { get; set; }
```

This is `NavButtonUsed`:

```cs
private bool NavButtonUsed { get; set; }
```

`CurrentItem` is bound to the selected item in my display ListBox with two-way binding, and the `ItemsSource` is bound to `ItemList`.  Please note that this is the Windows Store subsection of WPF, so I cannot just use a TreeView - that is why my submenus are prefixed with spaces:

```xml
<ListBox Name="Items" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
         Tapped="Items_Tapped" Margin="-2,-2,0,-2" Style="{Binding Theme, Converter={StaticResource LBStylePick}}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{Binding Theme, Converter={StaticResource LBIStylePick}}" Padding="0,10" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

So, when I press my back button and call GoBack, it sets a flag (boolean value, really) that indicates that I am using a navigation button.  Then, it adds the item at `Back[0]` (the currently selected item, actually), to `Forward` and removes the item at `Back[0]` so we don't just go back to the page we are currently on.  Next, if the current item's name starts with a space (which provides the indentation needed for submenus) and item's menu is not open, I run the `switch` block to open the menu:

```cs
if (Back[0].Title.StartsWith(" ") && CurrentItem.Menu != Back[0].Menu) { }
```

In the `switch` block, I find with menu needs to be opened and assign the main menu item to `CurrentItem`, which selects the menu through the data binding, which calls the `SelectionChanged` handler, which opens the menu:

```cs
switch (Back[0].Menu)
{
    case Menus.WSOneNote:
        CurrentItem = ItemList[0];
        break;
}
```

After the `if` block, I have the code to select the item that the user wants to go back to and set the navigation flag to false:

```cs
CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])];
NavButtonUsed = false;
```

This is the skeleton code for `SelectionChanged` for reference.  This is not the main focus of this post, but this also has a similar problem, so suggestions to solve this also are welcome - preferably if they kill both with one stone:

```cs
public void SelectionChanged(MenuItem newSelection)
{
    if (!NavButtonUsed) { Back.Insert(0, newSelection); }

    if (Forward.Count != 0 && !NavButtonUsed) { Forward.Clear(); }

    if (newSelection.Title.StartsWith(" ")) { return; }

    // Remove menu items to close menu - title starts with space
    ItemList.RemoveAll(item => item.Title.StartsWith(" "));

    switch (newSelection.Menu)
    {
        case Menus.WSOneNote:
            ItemList.Insert(1, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSNotes"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Notes), Menus.WSOneNote));
            ItemList.Insert(1, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSPages"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Pages), Menus.WSOneNote));
            ItemList.Insert(1, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSSections"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Section), Menus.WSOneNote));
            ItemList.Insert(1, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSNotebooks"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Notebook), Menus.WSOneNote));
            break;

        case Menus.WSMainMenu:
            ItemList.Insert(2, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSDraw"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Draw), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            ItemList.Insert(2, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSUndo"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Undo), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            ItemList.Insert(2, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTag"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Tag), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            ItemList.Insert(2, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSPaste"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Paste), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            ItemList.Insert(2, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSList"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.List), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            ItemList.Insert(2, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSTable"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Table), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            ItemList.Insert(2, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSInsertFile"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.FileInsert), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            ItemList.Insert(2, MenuItem.CreateMenuItem(resourceFile.GetString("WSPicture"), typeof(WindowsData.Submenus.Picture), Menus.WSMainMenu));
            break;

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: A dictionary might be a good replacement for `switch...case`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4233539/2101909

Comment: So I create a dictionary with a Key of Menus.(menu), and a Value of the corresponding MenuItem?  Then search it for the corresponding Key corresponding to the Menus.(menu) in `Back[0]`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your code well enough to be that specific. The key needs to be whatever type the `switch` takes and the value needs to evaluate to what `switch` returns. The big idea is that the value can even be a function (anonymous or not). Using a dictionary makes the call site simpler and allows changes in the dispatch without modifying the source for `GoBack()` once it gets accessor methods for the dictionary. Essentially dictionary use allows a data structure to replace a cumbersome procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Ben Rudger's suggestion to use a `Dictionary`, I realized that if the menu is closed, there is only one instance of a `MenuItem` in `ItemList` with the matching `Menus.Value`.  Because of this, all I have to do is iterate over `ItemList` until I find that matching value, choose that value, and exit the loop, so `GoBack` becomes this:

```cs
public void GoBack()
{
    NavButtonUsed = true;

    Forward.Insert(0, Back[0]);
    Back.RemoveAt(0);

    if (Back[0].Title.StartsWith(" ") && CurrentItem.Menu != Back[0].Menu)
    {
        foreach(MenuItem mi in ItemList)
        {
            if (mi.Menu == Back[0].Menu)
            {
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(mi)];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])];
    NavButtonUsed = false;
}
```

If the menu is open, we do not use the loop, but it still would work because the menu is still the first instance of `MenuItem` with its specific `Menus.Value` in the list.