# Going back with a Vengeance

Tags: c#

So I received a comment on my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78902/go-back-with-more-detail) that suggested creating a `Dictionary` of my menus to store the data in.  So that got me thinking, all I am doing is going back to the first instance of `MenuItem` in the `ItemList` that has a `Menu` of `Back[0].Menu`.  So why not just iterate through there and open the menu when I find it?

So, here is my final code:

```cs
public void GoBack()
{
    NavButtonUsed = true;

    Forward.Insert(0, Back[0]);
    Back.RemoveAt(0);

    if (Back[0].Title.StartsWith(" ") && CurrentItem.Menu != Back[0].Menu)
    {
        foreach(MenuItem mi in ItemList)
        {
            if (mi.Menu == Back[0].Menu)
            {
                CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(mi)];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(Back[0])];
    NavButtonUsed = false;
}
```

Everything else stayed the same as in my previous question, please check that for details.

Comment: This is looking much nicer and much simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `CurrentItem = ItemList[ItemList.IndexOf(mi)];`

can just be

```
CurrentItem = mi;
```

You could also use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var item = ItemList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Menu == Back[0].Menu);
if (item != null)
{
    CurrentItem = item;
}
```

Comment: Good points.  It is guaranteed that it will never be null in my particular case - it it was, more than one thing would be broken.

Comment: @Hosch250 ah, in that case you can just write `CurrentItem = ItemList.First(...)`.

Comment: Already did it..